# How to implement 'SELECT column_default' in a QGIS processing script?

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, sql, default

When creating a PostgreSQL serial value using the QGIS DB-Manager, the sequence is named `/*schema*/./*table*/_/*column*/_seq`.

[image]

I've created a processing script that drops the default value/sequence if there is no need for it:

[image]
[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#--------- define Interface
##PostgreSQL/PostGIS Tools=group
##Drop default value/sequence=name
##PostgreSQL_Table=vector
##Column=field PostgreSQL_Table

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import *

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

import psycopg2

#get the parameters for the tpg table into a directory
#get the table
pg_table = processing.getObject(PostgreSQL_Table)
#create empty dictionary for key/value pairs of the tables connection parameters
db_params = {}
db_params['clmn'] = Column
#iterate over connection string
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  Connection parameters')
for param in pg_table.dataProvider().dataSourceUri().split(' '):
    key_val = param.split('=')
    progress.setInfo(str(key_val))
    try:
        #set key/value pair
        db_params[key_val[0]] = key_val[1]
    except:
        pass

#generate the sql statement string
#the text in round brackets are the keys from the db_params dictionary created above
#the values belonging to the keys are inserted into the string
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  SQL statement')
sql = """ALTER TABLE %(table)s
ALTER COLUMN %(clmn)s DROP DEFAULT;
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS %(table)s_%(clmn)s_seq;
COMMIT;""" % db_params
#remove double quotes
sql = sql.replace('"','') 
progress.setInfo(sql)

#make connection string
constr = """dbname=%(dbname)s host=%(host)s port=%(port)s user=%(user)s password=%(password)s""" % db_params
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  DB Connection string')
progress.setInfo(constr)
#make db connection
con = psycopg2.connect(constr)
cur = con.cursor()
#execute the above created sql statement
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  Executing SQL statement ...')
cur.execute(sql)
progress.setInfo(20*'-' + '  ... done.')
```

I also want to drop the default value if the sequence is named different than `/*schema*/./*table*/_/*column*/_seq`? How can I implement the following SQL query in the processing script?

```
SELECT column_default
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE (table_schema, table_name, column_name) = ('/*schema*/', '/*table*/', '/*column*/');
```

Comment: What's the problem again if you execute it the very same way as the SQL in the bigger blob of code you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 3: 
This code should include what you need to make your script work. Additional discussion is below in the earlier responses (after the line):

```
import psycopg2
import re

db_name = 'DB_NAME'
db_user = 'DB_USER'
db_password = 'DB_PASSWORD'

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} password={2}".format(db_name, db_user, db_password))

schema = 'public'
table_name = 'temp_table'
column_name = 'gid'

with conn.cursor() as curs:
    # retrieve name of sequence from column default
    sql = """
            SELECT column_default FROM information_schema.columns
            WHERE table_schema = %s
            AND table_name = %s
            AND column_name = %s;
          """
    curs.execute(sql, (schema, table_name, column_name))

    seq_name = curs.fetchone()
    # Extract the sequence name from the result tuple.
    # need to remove result from list, only get text between quotes, 
    # and then remove that from a list format for a string to put in SQL.
    seq_name = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", seq_name[0])[0]

    # drop default from column, essentially converting serial to integer
    sql2 = """
            ALTER TABLE {0}.{1} ALTER COLUMN {2} DROP DEFAULT;
           """.format(schema, table_name, column_name)
    curs.execute(sql2)

    # drop sequence from database
    sql3 = """
            DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS {0}.{1};
           """.format(schema, seq_name)
    curs.execute(sql3)

    # commit changes if everything went OK
    conn.commit()
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

I'm not following everything you want to do, but may be able to get the conversation started on your ending question about how to execute the select statement. The following code returns [('false',)] on one of my databases - a tuple inside a list. You will need to do some indexing and conversion if you want this as Python False rather than a string in a tuple in a list.

You will need to assign the the variables in your script. Since you are using psycopg2, it will escape on %s, passed into the execute as tuples.

```
import psycopg2

db_name = 'DB NAME'
db_user = 'DB_USER'
db_password = 'DB_PASSWORD'

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} password={2}".format(db_name, db_user, db_password))

schema = 'topology'
table_name = 'topology'
column_name = 'hasz'

with conn.cursor() as curs:
    sql = """
            SELECT column_default FROM information_schema.columns
            WHERE table_schema = %s
            AND table_name = %s
            AND column_name = %s;
          """
    curs.execute(sql, (schema, table_name, column_name))

    print(curs.fetchall())
```

As an aside, if you use Python string formatting with the {} brackets in addition to the %s, you can develop a lot of flexibility in letting your script modify some parts of the SQL while still letting psycopg2 take care of escaping and date formats, etc based on the %s.

It sounds like you plan to incorporate the select with some SQL to delete or update rows, but I don't follow your plan quite well enough to take a stab at that.

EDIT:
While troubleshooting with psycopg2, I often find it useful to use a line like

```
print(curs.mogrify(sql, (schema, table_name, column_name)))
```

and comment out the actual execute statement. Mogrify will print out the SQL string that is being sent to Postgres, with all the text escaped, date formatting, etc. You can easily copy the text into pgAdmin for more direct experimenting without wondering if the problem is in SQL or Python.

EDIT 2:

From what I can put together, the only significant link between a column in a table and a sequence in Postgres is within the default value. The sequence lives as an object separate from the table and column itself. Therefore, when you drop the default from the column, you are removing the one thing that tells you what sequence the column is tied to. You should get this information prior to dropping the default. The SQL to return the column_default is above.

Once you execute this statement with a cursor and then fetchone, you will have a string similar to "nextval('background.temp_table_gid_seq'::regclass)". From here, you can use something like the Python in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735440/extract-a-string-between-double-quotes) to extract the name of the sequence and store it in a Python variable rather than printing like my code above. Then, after you drop the default, you can use the variable to [drop the sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-dropsequence.html).

In the end, you will be executing three SQL statements:

1. Find the name of the sequence from the column default.
2. Drop the column default, like you have done with ALTER COLUMN...
3. Drop the sequence using the result from the first SQL execution.

In psycopg2, each of these will be its own curs.execute() call. If all of that goes well, you can then commit the changes with conn.commit() after completing all three executes. You should be left with an integer primary key that has no default value and cannot be null, and the sequence should be deleted.

Disclaimer: there doesn't seem to be a whole lot on Google, etc. about going from a serial type to integer type. Most people are going the other way. [Here is one post I found](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5e744e3d0601270533we50387el2eee21477e681ad6%40mail.gmail.com) that is older but provides some information. I think you are safer querying the information_schema. I am not the best person to ask what other behind the scenes links or impacts may be caused by what you are doing, but I think the process above will get you to where you can delete the sequence even if it has been renamed.

Comment: Please use the QGIS DB-Manager to create a new PostGIS table (e.g. pgtable). The primary key (e.g. gid) should be data type 'serial'. The sequence of the PK is named 'pgtable_gid_seq'. You can drop the sequence running the Python script posted above in the QGIS processing toolbox ('Create new script'). But the script is not working when the sequence has been renamed before dropping it (e.g. 'ALTER SEQUENCE public.pgtable_gid_seq RENAME TO my_seq;').

Comment: @eclipsed_by_the_moon Please see EDIT 2 above.

Comment: @eclipsed_by_the_moon I just added a third edit at the top of the response that summarizes everything. I tested it on a temporary table in a PostGIS database and it appeared to work correctly.

Comment: After adding the host to psycopg2.connect(), the script in the third edit works really nice. There is just one regression: In the opening question the layer (schema, table, column) and the DB connection were set dynamically from the GUI. Now these parameters are static. I'm not sure if I can fix this, but I'll take a look on it.

Comment: I believe you can do that with something like table_name = db_params['table'] - simply replace the static string with a dictionary reference. I pulled them out in their own lines to make it clear where they are set.